# In C#, .Net 3.5, how can I add checkboxes to a TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, treeview

This is a codebase that I inherited, and the TreeView in the System.Windows.Controls namespace apparently does not support the CheckBoxes property.  I have tried to switch to System.Windows.Forms, but too much code had to be changed.  Is it possible to add checkboxes to a System.Windows.Control.TreeView, and if so, how? Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about WPF?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about WPF

Comment: Edited your tags to include `WPF`.

Comment: WPF is very flexible about the items you put in a TreeView, most anything goes.  Like CheckBox controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can by affecting a [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the treeview's ItemTemplate property. Just define your template to something like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxItemTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding YourNodeInnerElementsCollectionHere, Mode=OneTime}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding YourBooleanPropertyForCheck}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding YourStringPropertyForText, Mode=OneTime}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

And then set your treeview as follow:

```
<TreeView (...) ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}" (...) />
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a very trivial example of a templated treeview.

Project : WpfApplication4 (root namespace)

File 1: MyItemCollection.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public class MyItemCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MyItem>
    {

        public MyItemCollection()
        {
            Add(new MyItem() { MyText = "test", MyIsChecked = true });
            Add(new MyItem() { MyText = "test2", MyIsChecked = false  });
            Add(new MyItem() { MyText = "test3", MyIsChecked = false });
            Add(new MyItem() { MyText = "test4", MyIsChecked = true });

            this[0].MyInnerCollection.Add(new MyItem() { MyText = "innertest", MyIsChecked = true });
        }

    }

    public class MyItem
    {

        public MyItem()
        {
            _MyInnerCollection = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
        }

        // Fields...
        private System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MyItem> _MyInnerCollection;
        private bool _MyIsChecked;
        private string _MyText;

        public string MyText
        {
            get { return _MyText; }
            set
            {
                _MyText = value;
            }
        }

        public bool MyIsChecked
        {
            get { return _MyIsChecked; }
            set
            {
                _MyIsChecked = value;
            }
        }

        public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyInnerCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return _MyInnerCollection;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

File 2 : MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:MyItemCollection x:Key="ColObj"></local:MyItemCollection>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxItemTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding MyInnerCollection}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding MyIsChecked}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyText}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource ColObj}">
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Again, that's for demonstration purpose. :) It should give you the main idea around templates for treeview items.

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to play with margins and the like but this should get you started. :)

Comment: I copied your code exactly into my source.  When my tree was loaded I did not see any checkboxes, and I got these messages in my output:

Comment: `System.Windows.Data Error: 25 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are not valid for item.; Type='TreeViewItem'
System.Windows.Data Error: 25 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are not valid for item.; Type='TreeViewItem'`

Comment: I don't understand how you got that error. I updated my answer with a more complete example (please note it is for demonstration purposes) which runs exactly as expected on my side. Hope that helps. If not, I'm afraid you'll have to show some code. ;)

Comment: I was assuming that the template would work with my old code -- wrong.